# Troubleshooting Geeksforgeeks C Program: IEE 754 Notation to Decimal

Tags: c++, c, floating-point, binary

I have tried troubleshooting this code but as I am new to the C language I haven't been able to crack it. I am pulling this program from this article Geeksforgeeks created: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/program-for-conversion-of-32-bits-single-precision-ieee-754-floating-point-representation/

Every time I run this program in a separate C++ shell I get the following error: invalid conversion from 'unsigned int*' to 'int*' [-fpermissive]

Anyone have any ideas?

Here is the code:

```
// C program to convert 
// IEEE 754 floating point representaion 
// into real value 
  
#include <math.h> 
#include <stdio.h> 
  
typedef union { 
  
    float f; 
    struct
    { 
  
        // Order is important. 
        // Here the members of the union data structure 
        // use the same memory (32 bits). 
        // The ordering is taken 
        // from the LSB to the MSB. 
  
        unsigned int mantissa : 23; 
        unsigned int exponent : 8; 
        unsigned int sign : 1; 
  
    } raw; 
} myfloat; 
  
// Function to convert a binary array 
// to the corresponding integer 
unsigned int convertToInt(int* arr, int low, int high) 
{ 
    unsigned f = 0, i; 
    for (i = high; i >= low; i--) { 
        f = f + arr[i] * pow(2, high - i); 
    } 
    return f; 
} 
  
// Driver Code 
int main() 
{ 
  
    // Get the 32-bit floating point number 
    unsigned int ieee[32] 
        = { 1, 
            1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
            0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
            0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 }; 
  
    myfloat var; 
  
    // Convert the least significant 
    // mantissa part (23 bits) 
    // to corresponding decimal integer 
    unsigned f = convertToInt(ieee, 9, 31); 
  
    // Assign integer representation of mantissa 
    var.raw.mantissa = f; 
  
    // Convert the exponent part (8 bits) 
    // to a corresponding decimal integer 
    f = convertToInt(ieee, 1, 8); 
  
    // Assign integer representation 
    // of the exponent 
    var.raw.exponent = f; 
  
    // Assign sign bit 
    var.raw.sign = ieee[0]; 
  
    printf("The float value of the given"
           " IEEE-754 representation is : \n"); 
    printf("%f", var.f); 
}
```

Thank you to anyone who is willing to help out.

Comment: The error seems pretty clear - `convertToInt` is declared to take `int*` as an argument, but you are passing `unsigned int*` to it.

Comment: The shell you are using is probably using g++ to compile it. This is accually a c program  try "gcc file.c" on your own system. our use this online tool https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_c_compiler

Comment: That is a bad article with quite a number of problems in it and its code. I recommend not using that site. A good textbook would be better for learning.

Comment: Thank you to everyone who responded. I answered my own question with all of your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All I had to do to solve this question is remove the 'unsigned' in the following code:

```
unsigned int ieee[32] 
        = { 1, 
            1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
            0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
            0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
```

Thanks again for all the input!